# Laravel push notifications: certificate doesn't exist

Tags: php, ios, laravel-5, push-notification, certificate

I am trying to send push notifications in `Laravel` to an `iOS` application and I am using Laravel's [Push Notification Package](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification). This is my config file:

```
 return array(

        'appNameIOS' => array(
            'environment' => 'development',
            'certificate' => base_path('app/cert/APNS_Cert_Hasalty_dev.p12'),
//I am using absolute path in the actual code
            'passPhrase' => '',
            'service' => 'apns'
        ),
        'appNameAndroid' => array(
            'environment' => 'production',
            'apiKey' => 'yourAPIKey',
            'service' => 'gcm'
        )

    );
```

This is what I am doing to send the notification:

```
$payload = PushNotification::Message('Hello World, i`m a push message from hasalty', array(
            'badge' => 1,
            'sound' => 'default',
        ));

        PushNotification::app('appNameIOS')
            ->to($deviceToken)
            ->send($payload);
```

Now, the certificate file exists at the path given in the config but it throws me the error:

> Certificate
>   app/cert/APNS_Cert_Hasalty_dev.p12
>   does not exist

What am I doing wrong? Any help?
Laravel's version is `5.3.31`.

Comment: add your .p12 path not `path/to/APNS_Cert_Hasalty_dev.p12`, for e.g `'certificate' => '..../APNS_Cert_Hasalty_dev.p12',`(.... where you saved the p12 add that path to certificate)

Comment: i have updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: check once your path is valid or not, if it is valid check one the .p12 file is placed in the place or not

Comment: The path is correct, I have tried it with absolute path as well, but still the same error, so there is nothing wrong with the path.

Comment: are you seen the sample those are added the .pem file `'certificate' => '/path/to/certificate.pem',` not .p12, see this also `//Path to the 'app' folder
'certificate'=>app_path().'/myCert.pem'`

Comment: yeah, so .p12 file cant be used?

Comment: ya yes , add your pem file and check once

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I used the .pem file with still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. In fact I was using `.p12` file and changed it to `.pem` file and it worked. The difference b/w these can be studied [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use absolute path instead. `__DIR__`.'/path/to/certificate.pem'